# How to return from "partial curl" type segue

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode4, interface-builder

I am attempting to use a partial curl segue to reveal an options view *underneath* my main view. This is identical to touching the "page curl" button in the bottom right corner of the Maps app.

I can successfully execute the segue to the option view, my problem is returning to the main view. I'm hoping to replicate the reverse animation effect of the Maps app as the edge curls back flat and the main view is shown.

It doesn't seem logical to create another segue to return back to the main view (what I would do if I were not using the partial curl segue) because the return segue is associated with the original segue.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
-(IBAction) buttonPressed{
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

This should work!

Or i believe you can press the back side of the turned page and it will return automatically with out adding any code! Hope that helps!

Comment: ubt is there a solution that works within interface builder without creating an action

Answer (score 0):

In Swift dismissModalViewControllerAnimated has been renamed:

```
@IBAction func handleAddButton(_ sender: Any) {
    self.dismiss(animated:true, completion: {})
}
```